# Fast matrix Exponentiation computation in Galois field

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, galois-field

I am looking for a fast way to compute power of matrix A in galois field 2 ([GF(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2))). `A` is a double matrix and its exponentiation of `x` denoted by

```
A^x = A * A * A * ... * A     (x times)
```

The simple way is that converts `A` to GF(2) (because given matrix `A` is double matrix) and then peform exponentiation operation. 
Matlab code

```
A1 = gf(A, 2) % // convert to galois field
A_pow_x_first = A1^x; % // Perform A^x
```

However, this way takes long time to converts matrix `A` to GF(2). I am looking for a fast way without GF(2) converting. That is, I using mod operation

```
A_pow_x_second = mod(A^x, 2)
```

However, the problem is that the result of first way and second way are not similar. The problem is that overflow of number. Some member suggested to me convert matrix `A` to int64. However, I think it is not good way to handle with my problem. Could you suggest to me a fast way to do it in matlab? Thanks in advance

This is simple example

```
>> A = [1     0     1
        0     1     1
        1     1     1]
```

First way,

```
>> A_pow_x_first = gf(A, 2)^50
```

Result:

```
 0           1           0
 1           0           0
 0           0           1
```

Second way

```
>> A_pow_x_second = mod(A^50, 2)

A_pow_x_second =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

How to fast compute `A^x` without convert to GF(2) that has similar result in first way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matrix Exponentiation in Galois Field 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896346/matrix-exponentiation-in-galois-field-2)

Comment: Also: As you keep asking about [this paper](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/WIEDEMANN-IEEE-1986.pdf): Instead of computing `(A^i)*b`, you should instead compute `A*(A*(..*(A*b)))` [mod 2] using a `for` loop! And of course for computing `(A^(i+1))*b)` you should reuse the result of the previous computation `A*(A^i)*b`.

Comment: The problem you are having is not an overflow, it is the limited precision of the `double` data type. MATLAB (and IEEE 754) use 52 bits for the fraction and 11 bits for the exponent. With 52 bits for the fraction, you will get a precision of about 16 digits in the decimal system. This is never enough for the values you are having.

Comment: @knedlsepp: yes, In this topic, I just find the problem and I found this problem is overflow problem. And I make a new topic now to resolve it. In the topic, I also find a fast way to compute power of matrix that avoid overflow of number

Comment: @knedlsepp: What sentence said about my problem in that paper. It is truly problem that I am resolving for that paper. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @hbaderts: Good point. Do you suggest to me some fast way to resolve my problem. Let refer the topic to get more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896346/matrix-exponentiation-in-galois-field-2?noredirect=1#comment44202131_27896346

Comment: @user8264: You mind joining me in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68657/linear-systems-over-finite-field)?